# MediaElement freezing after 5 seconds every time

Tags: wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I am using a MediaElement for viewing both normal images and gif images, but the gifs freeze after 5 seconds every time. The ones that are longer than 5 seconds dont finish, while those who are less than 5 seconds get looped until it reaches that *magical* number.

Ive tried doing manual unload on the image, force playing it - nothing works.

```
    private void NewUri(string path)
    {
        MediaView.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);

        if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".gif")
        {
            isAnimated = true;
        }
        else
            isAnimated = false;

        OnImageChanged();

        GC.Collect();
    }
    private void OnImageChanged()
    {
        isPaused = false;

        MediaView.Play();

        border.Reset();
    }
    private void OnClipEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaView.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        MediaView.Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon more brute force testing I found out that writing `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);`instead of `TimeSpan.Zero;`fixes the issue, somehow.

I would still like to know why that is if anyone knows. But if it works, it works